# JOIN a table with a grouped by table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables i am trying to join and do a count on, basically to bring over the date onto the Units table. The problem is that the intakes table has duplicates.

```
SELECT 

   Units.Clinic,

   Units.display_id,

   INTAKES.initial_intake_date, 

   COUNT(case_note_type_desc) AS CountOfUAs

FROM Units

LEFT JOIN (SELECT display_id,Clinic,initial_intake_date 

                FROM factIntakesAndDischarges 

                GROUP BY display_id,Clinic,initial_intake_date ) INTAKES 

            ON Units.display_id = INTAKES.display_id

            AND Units.display_id = INTAKES.Clinic

WHERE casenotes_date BETWEEN '4/9/20' AND '5/9/20'

AND case_note_type_desc = '(UA)'


GROUP BY    Units.Clinic,

            Units.display_id,

            INTAKES.initial_intake_date

ORDER BY CountOfUAs desc,Clinic,display_id,initial_intake_date
```

This gives me the correct count, but the initial_intake_date comes back NULL. The other join i tried gave me the correct initial_intake_date, but the count was off.

Comment: What does the data look like? Is the initial intake date non-null all the time?

Comment: This condition: `AND Units.display_id = INTAKES.Clinic` is suspicious. Is it correct?

Comment: Please prepend each and every column with the table/alias where it's coming from.

Comment: Why all those `GROUP BY` and no aggregation???

Comment: AND Units.display_id = INTAKES.Clinic was a typo on my part, when pasting it over. I think i got the answer i needed with one of the reply below. In the learning stages of SQL, syntax is not the best yet. Thank you!

Comment: @j.m, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left of it. This rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too. [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your, I would really expect a query more like this:

```
SELECT u.Clinic, u.display_id, MIN(i.initial_intake_date) as initial_intake_date, 
       COUNT(*) AS CountOfUAs
FROM Units u LEFT JOIN
     factIntakesAndDischarges fid
     ON u.display_id = i.display_id AND
        u.display_id = INTAKES.display_id
WHERE u.casenotes_date >= '2020-04-09' AND '2020-05-09' AND
      u.case_note_type_desc = '(UA)'
GROUP BY u.Clinic, u.display_id,
ORDER BY CountOfUAs desc, Clinic, display_id, initial_intake_date;
```

Even if the numbers are not quite right, this is a simpler query for starting to fix.

Answer (score 0):

ON  Units.display_id = INTAKES.display_id
AND Units.display_id = INTAKES.Clinic

OR

ON  Units.display_id = INTAKES.display_id
AND Units.Clinic     = INTAKES.Clinic

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH UnitsTable AS
    (
        SELECT 
                Clinic
            ,   display_id
            ,   CountOfUAs  = COUNT(case_note_type_desc)
        FROM    Units
    )   
,   IntakesTable    AS
    (
        SELECT 
                display_id
            ,   Clinic
            ,   initial_intake_date 
        FROM    factIntakesAndDischarges 
        -- I am asuming casenotes_date and casenotes_type_Desc belong to Intakes
        -- If not, move this WHERE to UnitsTable above
        WHERE   
                    casenotes_date      BETWEEN '4/9/20' AND '5/9/20'
                AND case_note_type_desc =       '(UA)'
        GROUP BY 
                display_id
            ,   Clinic
            ,   initial_intake_date 
    ) 

SELECT
            U.Clinic
        ,   U.display_id
        ,   I.initial_intake_date
        ,   U.CountOfUAs
FROM        UnitsTable      U
    JOIN    IntakesTable    I   ON  I.Display_ID    =   U.Display_ID
                                AND I.Clinic        =   U.Clinic


ORDER BY 
            U.CountOfUAs desc
        ,   U.Clinic
        ,   U.display_id
        ,   I.initial_intake_date
```